# ошибка доступа к WCF в зависимости от размера передаваемых данных

Tags: .net, wcf

Имеется WCF сервис с практически дефолтными настройками.

```
    <bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
      <security mode="None">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

У него есть паблик метод, принимающий массив байт. При вызове данного сервиса и передачей ему массива размером ~10кб все ок. Однако, при увеличении размера массива до 30кб я получаю ошибку

```
http request was forbidden with client authentication scheme 'anonymous'
```

и метод просто не вызывается. Куда копать?

Comment: Думается мне что WCF здесь ни причем - смотрите настройки IIS-а  (например Request Filtering) если сервис на нем крутится.

Comment: настройки проверил, ничего криминального нет. RequestFiltering содержит только ограничения по расширениям файлов.